# WP7 - accessing selected item in listbox when listbox is within an itemtemplate

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, itemtemplate

I have a Pivot item template that includes a listbox

```
 <controls:Pivot x:Name="MainPivot" ItemsSource="{Binding PivotItemHeaders}" Title="CLASS TIMETABLE"  >
        <controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ListBox x:Name="Events" ItemsSource="{Binding allEventItems}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource EventDisplay2}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
    </controls:Pivot>
```

In the code behind I want to access the selectedItem of that listbox but I cannot 'get' to the listbox as such because ity is (presumably) within the template

i.e

```
this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/View/EventEdit.xaml?selectedEvent=" +  Events.SelectedItem, UriKind.Relative));
```

The Events listbox is not being recognised.

Assuminh I can pass get the object and pass it through as a parameter, what code can I use to retrieve it

I know its starts with 
     protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            if (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("SelectedEvent"))
            {

But I am unsure of the syntax/code to extract out the object from the parameters

Appreciate how I can get the selectedItem from this listbox and the code to get the object being passed through

- thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than attempt to access the ListBox, you could use the [`SelectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectionchanged%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) event to be told when the value changes:

```
<ListBox x:Name="Events" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding allEventItems}" 
         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource EventDisplay2}"
         SelectionChanged="Event_SelectionChanged" />
```

And then in your code behind:

```
private void Event_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    this.selectedEvent = (EventItem)e.AddedItems[0];
}
```

You can access the value using `NavigationContext.QueryString["selectedEvent"]`, but you can only store strings in navigation query strings. If your listbox is currently bound to objects, you'll need to select a key and then find that event from the second page using that key.

Comment: So you are suggesting I capture the latest item that has been selected  (via the SelectionChanged event) and then at the time I want to navigate I take the key from this object and pass that through.